# Has Many relationship causing memory error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I have model "Sites" that hasMany "TrialCase".

Site Model

```
public function trialCases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\Trial1\TrialCase', 'site_id');
}
```

TrialCase model

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\Site');
}
```

(TrialCase is in the Trial1 namespace)

When I try and call the site() method on a TrialCase like so:

```
<?php var_dump($case->site()); ?>
```

I get a whitescreen, and my php error log shows an insufficient memory error, as though it's infinite looping. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. All other case properties work fine (ie: $case->id). And if I change the ->site() method to just echo out a string, it works fine as well. So it seems the problem is that with my has many relationship. How am I screwing this up?

EDIT: also, if I manually build an eloquent where query like so:

```
Site::where('id', '=', $case->site_id)->first()->site_name
```

It works just fine.

Comment: I do not. TrialCase only has a site_id column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using:

```
$case->site->name
```

or

```
var_dump($case->site);
```